# How to set window size to get full-page screenshot with selenium and chrome headless webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to obtain a full-page screenshot through chrome headless mode and selenium in python. It works well when I set the window-size as following before browser.get(url)

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size={},{}".format(1024, 1920))
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(tt)
pic_path = os.path.join(path, name)

if browser.save_screenshot(pic_path):
    print('Done!')
else:
    print('Failed!')
print(pic_path)

browser.quit()
```

However, I don't know the exact window size of each webpage in advance. Therefore I need to get the window size after browser.get(url) as following

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)

width = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollWidth")
height = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size={},{}".format(width, height))
time.sleep(tt)
pic_path = os.path.join(path, name)

if browser.save_screenshot(pic_path):
    print('Done!')
else:
    print('Failed!')
print(pic_path)

browser.quit()
```

Yet it seems that the "add_argument" doesn't work after browser_get(url). I tried using

```
browser.set_window_size(width, height)
```

instead of

```
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size={},{}".format(width, height))
```

but an error occured like

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
>   from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html

which I don't understand and cannot find solution.

Hence, now I can get a full-page screenshot if I know the width and height before getting the url, but I don't know the width and height untill I get the url, which drives me crazy.

Comment: I make it by a two-step way: 1) visit the page to get the width and height; 2) get the screenshot with the width and height from step (1). But still curious if there are any ways to do it directly

Comment: `browser.set_window_size` should be a good approach, however, judging by the error you are getting, you are on an out of date chromedriver version. Upgrade chromedriver ([see here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)). Before you upgrade have a look at [choosing the correct chromedriver version](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection).